# Can we autowire a class instance in a custom Thread class?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc

I have class that extends Thread class like this below :

```
public class A extends Thread {  

    public void run() {
      System.out.println("in thread");
    }

}
```

I have a service class like this below :

```
@Service
public class Service {

    public void someMethod() {
      .....
    } 

}
```

How can I autowire a service class instance inside my thread class ?

Answer (score 2):

You can definately autowire.

example is below.

```
@Component
class A extends Thread{

 @Autowired
 Service service;

 public void run(){
      System.out.println("HI");
     serivce.anyMethod();
 }
```

}

> you should register your thread class in spring application context by @component,@service   or creating bean by @bean in configuration class.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for your question is YES. You can use autowired in thread class.

Have a look [at this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42502362/6572971)

Answer (score 1):

You can make `class A` a Spring component and then inject the dependency:

```
@Component
class A extends Thread{  
    public void run()
    {
     System.out.println("in thread");
    }

}
```

That said, pay extra care to what you are doing inside the `run()`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can autowire, as our colleagues have already suggested.  However, I would like to stress one point: the class must be a spring bean. Spring can autowire something only if the class itself is managed by Spring.

Once you do that, you should understand that by default spring creates a bean by calling `new A()` during the initialization, but it won't call `start` for you. Another interesting insight is that this `Thread` will be created only once (by default all beans are singletons in spring) so if you want many instances of `A` you might want to declare it as Prototype Scope.